# In-Memory Optimized Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got some challenges with In Memory-Optimized Tables (IMOT):
the index maintenance. Practically speaking, IMOT doesn't support conventional index maintenance such as REBUILD or REORGANIZE.

I set DROP and ADD the indexes. Can anyone recommend a better technique. Maybe the index maintenance no needed over IMOT objects?

Comment: In memory indexes virtually do not fragment. They do not need to be rebuilt. The indexes will be rebuilt when SQL Server restarts.